# split csv by year with batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, split

i'm trying to split a csv file based on the year. The year is allways shown in UTC Format after first delimiter ";".

**example for csv file:**

```
ID;Datum;EUR
1;2021-12-12 12:12:12;50
1;2020-12-12 12:12:12;10
2;2020-12-12 12:12:12;20
1;2019-12-12 12:12:12;80
```

So far I have the following **batch code** as a **solution**.

```
findstr /I /R /C:"^[^;]*;2019-" "test.csv" > "test_year1.csv"
findstr /I /R /C:"^[^;]*;2020-" "test.csv" > "test_year2.csv"
findstr /I /R /C:"^[^;]*;2021-" "test.csv" > "test_year3.csv"
```

It works but how can i add the first line (Header) to each of this splitfiles?

Also, the code is a bit simple and unwieldy. Is it possible to automate the whole thing a bit and automatically determine the possible year's from inputfile and create a corresponding output file?

thx for help,
SaXe

Comment: `for /L %%I in (2019,1,2022) do %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^[^;]*;%%I- ID;Datum;EUR" "test.csv" >"test_%%I.csv"` is one solution which is searching for `^[^;]*;%%I-` __OR__ `ID;Datum;EUR` because of space in a search string not specified with `/C:` is interpreted as __OR__. Another one is `for /L %%I in (2019,1,2022) do echo ID;Datum;EUR>"test_%%I.csv"& %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /C:"^[^;]*;%%I-" "test.csv" >>"test_%%I.csv"` which first creates the CSV file with the header without trailing space on using exactly this command line and then appends the find results.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, filenames, output filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q71435963.txt"

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

:: set environment variables #year#yearnumber# from sourcefile
FOR /f "skip=1usebackqtokens=2delims=-;" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "#year#%%b#=Y"

:: set "line1" to first line of file
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "line1=%%b"&GOTO buildfiles

:buildfiles
:: for each year found, create a new file & append data
FOR /f "tokens=2delims=#" %%b IN ('set # 2^>nul') DO (
  >"%destdir%\test_%%b.csv" ECHO %line1%
 >>"%destdir%\test_%%b.csv" findstr /I /R /C:"^[^;]*;%%b-" "%filename1%"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The `2^>nul` in each of the `set` commands suppresses error messages that would occur if there are no variables matching the pattern currently set. The `^` "escapes" the `>`, telling `cmd` that the `>` is part of the `set`, not of the `for`.

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

--------- Fix for `-` in column 1:

in place of the `for /f "skip...` line, use

```
FOR /f "skip=1usebackqtokens=2delims=;" %%c IN ("%filename1%") DO FOR /f "delims=-" %%b IN ("%%c") DO SET "#year#%%b#=Y"
```

This assigns the string from the second to third occurrence of `;` which grabs the second column to `%%c`, skipping the first line. Then the variable is set as before using the value of `%%c`, using `-` as a delimiter and selects the first token (ie. `%%c`up to the first delimiter)  into `%%b` as before. The default for `tokens=` is `tokens=1`.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer.

I understand the code so far.I have a question though, why doesn't it work if I use "%filename1%"  instead of hard coded "test" in the line of code 

>>"%destdir%\test_%%b.csv" findstr /I /R /C:"^[^;]*;%%b-" "%filename1%"

The filename1 value was defined at the beginning of the code.

Comment: I can't see what you've changed; you would need to change it in the previous line, too. I am using full filenames, so if you've simply changed `test` to `%filename1%` then the destination filename would be `%destdir%\%filename1%_%%b.csv` and since `filename1` contains a `:`, that would create a bad filename.

Comment: i see it for myself :) change %destdir%\test to %filename1% and it works :) thx again

Comment: one more question, sry `FOR /f "skip=1usebackqtokens=2delims=-;" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "#year#%%b#=Y"` set variables of the year. If in my Case `Column ID` also have a delimiter like `-`for example `4712-9999-12;2021-12-12 12:12:12;50` the code dosnt work anymore. Is ther another solution for identify the Year out of the UTC Format?

Comment: thx again for helping me :)